# Mysql inner join -> if null return null else return name

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    projects.id AS project_id,
    projects.name AS project_name,
    projects_tasks.id AS task_id,
    projects_tasks.name AS task_name,
    projects_tasks_timings.id AS timing_id,
    projects_tasks_timings.registered_time AS timing_time,
    projects_tasks_timings.edit_reason AS timing_description,
    projects_tasks_timings.date AS timing_date,
    projects_tasks_timings.created_at AS timing_date2,
    projects_tasks_timings.updated_at AS timing_date3,
    users.name AS timing_user_name,
    users.surname AS timing_user_surname,
    users2.name AS timing_user_name_update,
    users2.surname AS timing_user_surname_update
FROM `projects_tasks_timings`
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON users.id = projects_tasks_timings.user_id
INNER JOIN `users` 
    AS users2 ON users2.id = projects_tasks_timings.updated_by
INNER JOIN `projects_tasks` 
    ON projects_tasks.id = projects_tasks_timings.task_id
INNER JOIN `projects` 
    ON projects.id = projects_tasks.project_id
$task_clause
$user_clause
LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start
```

This should return a lot of data, but it doesn't. I think because the `inner join` on `users2` doesn't match any columns as they are all `null` values.

What I want to achieve is:

If it has no matches it should return null. If there are matches, it should return the users' names.

I've look through some question using a where clause on the inner join, but had no success so far.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use LEFT JOIN instead if INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
    projects.id AS project_id,
    projects.name AS project_name,
    projects_tasks.id AS task_id,
    projects_tasks.name AS task_name,
    projects_tasks_timings.id AS timing_id,
    projects_tasks_timings.registered_time AS timing_time,
    projects_tasks_timings.edit_reason AS timing_description,
    projects_tasks_timings.date AS timing_date,
    projects_tasks_timings.created_at AS timing_date2,
    projects_tasks_timings.updated_at AS timing_date3,
    users.name AS timing_user_name,
    users.surname AS timing_user_surname,
    users2.name AS timing_user_name_update,
    users2.surname AS timing_user_surname_update
FROM `projects_tasks_timings`
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON users.id = projects_tasks_timings.user_id
INNER JOIN `projects_tasks` 
    ON projects_tasks.id = projects_tasks_timings.task_id
INNER JOIN `projects` 
    ON projects.id = projects_tasks.project_id
LEFT JOIN `users` 
    AS users2 ON users2.id = projects_tasks_timings.updated_by
$task_clause
$user_clause
LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start
```